# How to reuse bind variables in oracledb-python?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

I'm trying to do an upsert with below query but I'm getting `oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4009: 11 positional bind values are required but 5 were provided`. Meaning I'm unable to reuse my bind variables.

```sql
UPDATE Competition 
SET abbreviation = :1, descriptions = :2, levels = :3, source = :4, competitionId = :5
WHERE competitionId=:5;
IF ( sql%notfound ) THEN
    INSERT INTO Competition
    VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5);
END IF;
```

The query is executed in the context:

```
cursor.executemany(upsert_string, parsed_data)
```

where the `upsert_string` is the above query and `parsed_data` is a list of tuples.

How do I reuse bind variables in this context, is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. There are a few options available to you.

1. You can use bind by *name* instead of bind by *position*. In your example it might look like this:

```sql
BEGIN
    UPDATE Competition SET
        abbreviation = :abbrev,
        descriptions = :descr,
        levels = :levels,
        source = :source
    WHERE competitionId = :compet;
    IF ( sql%notfound ) THEN
        INSERT INTO Competition
        VALUES (:abbrev, :descr, :levels, :source, :compet);
    END IF;
END;
```

2. Since this is an anonymous PL/SQL block, you can also store the bind values in temporary variables, like this:

```sql
DECLARE
    t_Abbrev        varchar2(10);
    t_Description   varchar2(100);
    t_Levels        varchar2(50);
    t_Source        varchar2(100);
    t_CompetitionId number;
BEGIN
    t_Abbrev := :1;
    t_Description := :2;
    t_Levels := :3;
    t_Source := :4;
    t_CompetitionId := :5;
    UPDATE Competition SET
        abbreviation = t_Abbrev,
        descriptions = t_Description,
        levels = t_Levels,
        source = t_Source
    WHERE competitionId = t_CompetitionId;
    IF ( sql%notfound ) THEN
        INSERT INTO Competition
        VALUES (t_Abbrev, t_Description, t_Levels, t_Source, t_CompetitionId);
    END IF;
END;
```

3. Finally, you can use the MERGE statement instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```sql
MERGE INTO Competition C USING (
    SELECT
        :1 as ABBREV,
        :2 as DESCRIPTION,
        :3 as LEVELS,
        :4 as SOURCE,
        :5 as COMPETITION_ID
    FROM DUAL
) S
ON (C.CompetitionId = S.COMPETITION_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE COMPETITION SET
        Abbreviation = s.ABBREV,
        Descriptions = s.DESCRIPTION,
        Levels = s.LEVELS,
        Source = s.SOURCE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO Competition VALUES (
        s.ABBREV,
        s.DESCRIPTION,
        s.LEVELS,
        s.SOURCE,
        s.COMPETITIONID
    )
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you for providing all these examples and mainly thank you for pointing out that I was trying to bind by position (did not know that). Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Just to provide some feedback, the second snippet worked right of the bat! While the first oddly enough still had the same complaint (`oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4009: 10 positional bind values are required but 5 were provided`). The third throw `oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword` (guessing something in the syntax). Again thank you for taking your time to help!

Comment: Read on the docs, that I need to pass a dict so that the name binding works, right now I am passing a tuple! Will test passing a dict instead

Comment: Yes, you need to pass a dict for bind by name. :-) I found the syntax error in the MERGE statement and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit stunned regarding the first query, it works seamlessly in the oracle cloud console, but throws `oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when executed from the python library

Comment: The cloud console may automatically wrap the code when it detects PL/SQL. You can simply put BEGIN and END around it. I'll update my answer so that it does that.

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing that out! Was not able to find that in the documentation, thank you!